# How to get the value of a selected radio button before the change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, slideshow

I have multiple radio button sharing the same name. One of them has a hidden div next to It.

When the correct radio button is selected, I want to show/hide the div that is next it to it "if one is there"

Here is an example

Radio 1
Radio 2
Radio 3
Radio 4

Next to Radio 2 there is a hidden div. I want to show it when Radio 2 is selected. Then when Radio 4 is selected, I want to hide the Radio 2 div

Here is what I have done

```
$(function(){

    function getGroupElement(value)
    {
        return '#group_' + value.replace(':', '_');
    }




  var previous;   

    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = $(this).val();

        console.log('Current:' + previous);

    }).change(function(e) {

        var previousGroupId = getGroupElement(previous);

        var newGroupName = $(this).data('show-group');

        //Hide the previous Group
        $(previousGroupId).hide();

        if ( ! newGroupName){
            return;
        }

        $(newGroupName).show();

    });

});
```

My code above is not working because previous is set to the next selected item.

How can I hide/show the correct box?

If needed here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset class="survey-control-fieldset">
        <div class="survey-control-title">
            Select a store
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="item_529"><input checked id="item_529" name=
            "control_111" type="radio" value="112:529"> None</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="item_530"><input id="item_530" name="control_111" type=
            "radio" value="112:530"> Don't Know/No Answer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="item_532"><input data-show-group="group_112_532" id=
            "item_532" name="control_111" type="radio" value="112:532">
            Other</label>
            <div id="group_112_532" style="display: none;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="control_113">Specify Other Store Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="control_113" name=
                    "control_113" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="item_531"><input id="item_531" name="control_111" type=
            "radio" value="112:531"> Refused</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML instead of describing it.

Comment: Why do you need the `previous` variable? Just hide all the DIVs, and show the one next to the selected button.

Comment: @Barmar how would I know the div id to hide? I added my HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide all the DIVs that are next to radios, then show the one next to the selected radio.

```
$(":radio").next("div").hide();
$(this).next("div").show();
```

Comment: Thank you. I took your advise from the comment above. where I have all of my div the same class name. Hide all then show the current one

Answer (score 0):

If you give each of the hidden div's the same class name, you can just hide them all before you show the new one:

```
$('.hidden-divs').not(newGroupName).hide();
$(newGroupName).show();
```